# Write values from a powershell file into variables of the wrapping batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

**MyBatScript.bat:**

```
PowerShell.exe "call MyPowershellScript.ps1"
%Tag% = NotSet
%CommitId% = NotSet
```

**MyPowershellScript.ps1:**

```
REM override the NotSet default value of tag and commitId defined in the MyBatScript.bat
$longVersion = git describe --long
$versionTokenList = $longVersion.Split('-')
%Tag% = $versionTokenList[0]
%CommitId% = $versionTokenList[-1]
```

I want to write the Tag and CommitId value from the powershell script called by the wrapping batch file into 2 batch variables.

How can I do that? At the moment the code above works not...

**NOTE**: I know you guys will ask my why I mix old bat with powershell.
I did not do that... its the mess of someone else I just have to fix the crap and I really need to do it this way... Thanks for your patience and understanding.

Comment: Do you want to set the `tag` and `commitid` batch file environment variables with output from the powershell script?

Comment: why `$versionTokenList[-1]` ? Wouldn't this produce index out of array error?

Comment: @foxidrive YES I want to return Tag and commitId value from powrshell script to the parent tag and commit variables.

Comment: @npocmaka No, -1 means last element of array.

Comment: @foxidrive I do not understand you. As I said this "%Tag% = $versionTokenList[0]" does not write the version to the batch %Tag% variable!

Comment: Your powershell script doesn't seem to work here: `git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file`

Comment: @Elisabeth Your powershell script needs to write text to the screen and  that text can be placed into the variables by the batch script.  Knowing what the script prints to the screen, and which text is for which variable, will let us give you reliable advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%varname%` is batch syntax for variables. It's not valid in a PowerShell script. The canonical way to return values from a PowerShell script to a parent batch script is to echo the values in the PowerShell script (for instance as a semicolon-separated string):

```psh
$longVersion = git describe --long
'{0};{1}' -f $longVersion.Split('-')[0,-1]
```

and process the output with a loop in the batch script:

```batch
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%a in (
  'PowerShell.exe -File "MyPowershellScript.ps1"'
) do (
  set "Tag=%%a"
  set "CommitId=%%b"
)
```